# Is the 'name' attribute considered outdated for <a> anchor tags?

Tags: html, visual-studio, tags, xhtml

Visual Studio doesn't like on-page anchor tags:

> Validation (XHTML 1.0 Transitional):
>   Attribute 'name' is considered
>   outdated. A newer construct is
>   recommended.

I'm using `name` attributes in this way…

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemalocation="http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/SCHEMA/xhtml11.xsd" xml:lang="en">
    ...
    <body>
        ...
        <p>On this page&hellip;</p>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#one">Section One</a></li>
            ...
        </ul>
        ...
        <h2><a name="one">Section One</a></h2>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there really a more-modern way of doing this?  Or is Visual Studio full of crap?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should use the `id` attribute instead. Works the same way, and you don't need an artifical `<a name=...>`, but simply

```
<h2 id="one">Section One</h2>
```

Comment: NOT TRUE! id MUST BE UNIQUE THROUGHOUT THE WHOLE DOCUMENT, while name can be shared with many elements. also, getElementsByName returns a list of elements. getElementById only return 1 single element.

Comment: @hanshenrik This answer does not say to always use `id` instead of `name`. Please do note the circumstances outlined in the question. It asks about how to link to a section. If you have duplicate names, linking to them is meaningless in the first place. In any case, if you want to identify multiple elements for programming purposes, you should use classes, not `name` attributes.

Answer (score 16):

name attributes are deprecated in [XHTML 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/) - you can use an id attribute in the same way though, see [Fragment Identifiers](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#C_8) in the [HTML Compatibility Guidelines](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#guidelines) of the XHTML spec.

So you can simply use

```
<h2><a id="one">Section One</a></h2>
```

But note that the 1.0 spec recommends playing it safe with something like this:

```
<h2><a name="one" id="one">Section One</a></h2>
```

However, your fragment uses [XHTML 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/), where the name attribute has been [entirely removed](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/changes.html#a_changesc) from `a` and `map` elements - so you can only use an id.

Comment: Actually, the fragment in the question is XHTML 1.1, which means that `name` is not just deprecated, it's plain illegal.

Comment: Well spotted, I missed that he was using 1.1 - will amend answer

Comment: I'm assuming 1.1 still has the name attribute for the input tag, though... I don't have time to check it at the moment.

Comment: I should explain why I assume it still have the name attribute for input: radio buttons all have the same name, and checkboxes are also allowed to have the same name to have their values grouped together.

Comment: sorry, yes I overstated - it's removed from a and map tags

Comment: @PaulDixon What about HTML 5?

Answer (score 3):

I believe the modern approach is to use the `id` attribute, which would be evaluated as an anchor. For example, if you changed

```
<h2><a name="one">Section One</a></h2>
```

to

```
<h2><a id="one">Section One</a></h2>
```

You would still address it as `page.html#one`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also link on a section header :

## Table of Contents

```
<P>
    <A href="#section1">Introduction</A><BR>
    <A href="#section2">Some background</A><BR>
    <A href="#section2.1">On a more personal note</A><BR>
    ...the rest of the table of contents...
    ...the document body...

    <H2 id="section1">Introduction</H2>
    ...section 1...

    <H2 id="section2">Some background</H2>
    ...section 2...

    <H3 id="section2.1">On a more personal note</H3>
    ...section 2.1...

[...]
</P>
```

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/links.html

Answer (score 1):

I believe the proper way to do it is <a id="one">

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is outdated. You should replace with the "id" attribute.

Quoting w3schools page:

> "*The id Attribute Replaces The name Attribute
>   HTML 4.01 defines a name attribute for the elements a, applet, frame, iframe, img, and map. In XHTML the name attribute is deprecated. Use id instead.*"

http://www.w3schools.com/Xhtml/xhtml_syntax.asp

Answer (score 1):

name= attributes are for labeling elements in a form, and can only be used on <form> elements (input, textarea, select etc).  For everything else, ID= is used.  Exactly why the W3C folks thought two different ways of naming an element (with different sets of allowable characters) were needed is not readily known.

Answer (score 1):

But here http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3 I read this: "Some older user agents don't support anchors created with the id attribute." So?

Comment: So nobody should be using those older user agents any more; they are full of security holes anyway. And if you as a webdeveloper want to support, say, Netscape 4, you've got bigger problems than that a URI with a `#` won't jump to the correct location.

Answer (score 0):

Until `<a name="..."></a>` is no longer supported by the (X)HTML standard you are using--and not just deprecated--it may be safest to use both `name` and `id` on anchors linking to a part of the same page.  From the [W3C's XHTML 1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#C_8):

> In XML, URI-references [RFC2396](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#ref-rfc2396) that end with fragment 
>   identifiers of the form `"#foo"` do not refer to elements with an attribute `name="foo"`; rather, 
>   they refer to elements with an attribute defined to be of type ID, e.g., the `id` attribute in HTML 
>   4. Many existing HTML clients don't support the use of ID-type attributes in this way, so identical 
>   values may be supplied for both of these attributes to ensure maximum forward and backward 
>   compatibility (e.g., `<a id="foo" name="foo">...</a>)`.