# How is this if statement working with comma?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

there is a if statement

```
if ((sliding || "Window" == type) &&
    nbCasement % 2 != 1 || sliding || "Garage" == type || f({
    name: "hinge"
}),
    nbCasement > 0 && !sliding && f({
    name: "side"

}),
    d && apiProperty)
```

with `&&` `||` and `,`

I thought it's same with this code:

```
f({
    name: "hinge"
});
f({
    name: "side"
});
if ((sliding || "Window" == type) &&
    nbCasement % 2 != 1 || sliding || "Garage" == type ||
    nbCasement > 0 && !sliding &&
    d && apiProperty)
```

but the result is different what I thought.

How is this statement working?
which condition make `f({name:xxx})` run?

the `f` defind is

```
  var e = []
          , f = function(a) {
            d && d.blackList && d.blackList[a.name] || e.push(a)
        };
```

Comment: Some context might help us you know...

Comment: It would also help if you explained why you thought those code snippets are equivalent so that it would be easier to tell what part of your thought process was wrong. For example, why do you think that both `f()` calls would always run (and their return values would be discarded)?

Comment: Where did you find this code? In some minified script? That would explain the formatting.

Comment: @Bergi yess. from minified script. hard to understand

Comment: @Juhana because from here http://stackoverflow.com/a/5348007/1204882 . I think the `f()` always run.

Comment: @chanjianyi: Try to get the original, instead of trying to understand minifier trickery :-)

Comment: But the `f()` calls aren't alone in the expressions. The comma operator doesn't negate the `&&` and `||` operators there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) just evaluates everything, before returning the last value. Your snippet is equivalent to

```
(sliding || "Window" == type) && nbCasement % 2 != 1 || sliding || "Garage" == type || f({
    name: "hinge"
});
nbCasement > 0 && !sliding && f({
    name: "side"
});
if (d && apiProperty)
```

which can be cleaned up and prettified to

```
if (!sliding) {
    if (("Window" != type || nbCasement % 2 == 1) && "Garage" != type)
        f({
            name: "hinge"
        });
    if (nbCasement > 0)
        f({
            name: "side"
        });
}
if (d && apiProperty)
```

Comment: Thankyou! but forget the `sliding` .  why  `nbCasement > 0 && !sliding && f({
    name: "side"
});` ==  `if (nbCasement > 0) {f({ name: "side" });}`

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6970346/1048572) and notice that this part became `if (!sliding) { if (nbCasement > 0) f({…}); }`