# What does return void 0 === i && (i = 3), 0 === i ? ( ..A.. ) : ( ..B.. ) do?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, comma-operator

I came to this code but I don't understand very well what it does..

```
test.update = function(i) 
{ 
return void 0 === i && (i = 3), 0 === i ? (..A..) : (..B..) 
}
```

(..A..) and (..B..) are just other lines of code I haven't posted.

Let's say if `i` would have a 0 value, what the function will return?

What does "void 0 === i && (i = 3)" do? Specially `(i = 3)`. Does that mean that `if (void 0 === i)` is true and `i` can get 3, `i` will be 3? And what about the comma? I've checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347995/why-does-javascript-accept-commas-in-if-statements) but I still don't get it.

Sorry for so many questions but I'd like to have a complete answer so I can totally understand what is going on.

Thank you

Comment: I guess it just executes `(..B..)` block of statements whatever `i` value is passed.

Comment: `void 0 === i` seems to check whether `i` is `undefined`. `i = 3` sets `i` to the number 3 when `i` in not undefined.

Comment: `0 === i` checks whether `i` is `0` and then does either `(..A..)` or `(..B..)`. This return uses the [comma](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) and [ternary operations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Comment: if that can help `void expression` is used when you want to evaluate the expression, but that the value returned is always `undefined`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, first let's set brackets according to [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence):

```
return (((void 0) === i) && (i = 3)), ((0 === i) ? A : B)
```

Now to the single operations

```
void 0
```

simply returns `undefined`. We could also write it this way:

```
undefined === i
```

which obviously checks whether `i` is undefined.

```
i = 3
```

looks like a comparison first, but in fact it's an assignment that returns `3`. So far the line looks up whether `i` is undefined and in case it is, it is assigned the value `3`.

Now the following comma is an operator on its own. It evaluates all expressions from left to right and returns the last one (right-most). In this case the last expression is a comparison of `0` and `i`. Means if `i` is `0` at this point, the return value of the whole expression is `true`.

As last there comes a conditional operator which is a short way to write `if .. else ..`.

So far the line could have been also written as:

```
if (i === undefined) {
  i = 3;
}
if (i === 0) {
  // return ( A )
}
else {
  // return ( B )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just run it and see that the first thing is returning undefined no matter what the rest does

if i ===0, run A, else run B and if i =="", i=3 -> run b

```js
var test= {}
test.update = function(i)  { 
  return void 0 === i && (i = 3), 0 === i ? (console.log(i,"a")) : (console.log(i,"b"))
}

console.log("i is null, res:"+test.update(null));
console.log("no i, res:"+test.update());
console.log("i blank, res:"+test.update(""));
console.log("i=0,res:"+test.update(0));
console.log("i=1,res:"+test.update(1));
console.log("i=2,res:"+test.update(2));
console.log("i=3,res:"+test.update(3));
```

Answer (score 1):

The rest is important, because the [`void` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void) evaluates the expression and returns `undefined`.

For example if the expression is a function call, like

```
return void func();
```

then the function is called and `void` returns `undefined`, even if `func` is returning something different.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it just executes (..B..) block of statements whatever i value is passed.

- `void` operator evaluates its operand and then returns `undefined`
  not depending of result of evaluation;
- `comma` operator just evaluates one thing, then another, left to right (like in `var i = 0, j = 0;`)
- `0 === i && (i = 3)` sets `i` to `3` if `i` equals `0`
- `0 === i ? (..A..) : (..B..)` executes `A` or `B` block of statements, but as said above, it is guaranteed at this moment that `i` is not equal to `0`.