# calling a javascript from a input element

Tags: javascript, html

I have an email contact form linked to a php script which is working, but I want to check if the fields are empty, if so, the text input container will change the background color.

this is part of the html code:

```
<!--START CONTACT FORM CONTAINER -->
<div id="form_container">

<form name="contact_form" method="post" action="php_script/email.php">
<div class="contact">
<form action="" method="get"></form>
<label>First Name</label>
<input name="first_name" type="text"/>

<form action="" method="get"></form>
<label>Last Name</label>
<input name="last_name" type="text"/>

<form action="" method="get"></form>
<label>Email Address</label>
<input name="email_address" type="text"/>

<label>Comment</label>
<textarea name="comments" cols="" rows=""></textarea>

<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

<input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

how can I call a javascript from  ?

Comment: look for form onsubmit

Comment: Did you even bother to Google this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937513/javascript-validation-for-empty-input-field

Answer (score 0):

Use the OnSubmit method of the form tag:

```
<FORM OnSubmit="somemethod()">
```

Return false to hinder submission.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It is the simplest possible answer (AFAIK), but it works. +1.

Comment: I guess we get penalized for answering simple questions with simple answers rather than giving the op shit for not googling.. go figure.