# Using isset from a name of an input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, if-statement

I am not sure if I am going about this correctly. I have a set of checkbox inputs. If someone selects the last check box `all_users_check`, I want a new form to appear where I will be listing all of the users in a drop down (haven't added the drop down yet). I thought I could do this by using the name of the input, but I am mistaken apparently as I am getting this error..

How else could I structure what I am doing so that if someone checks that option the new form displays?

```
<div class="user_dropdown">
<form action="">
  <input type="checkbox" name="spectator_check" value=""> Spectators<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="member_check" value="" checked> Team Members<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="commissioner_check" value="" checked> Commissioner(s)<br>
   <label for="all_users_check">
  <input type="checkbox" name="all_users_check" value="" checked> Individual User<br>
  </label>
</form>
</div>

<script>
$(".user_dropdown").hide();
$(".all_users_check").click(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(".user_dropdown").show();
    } else {
        $(".user_dropdown").hide();
    }
});
</script>
```

This is how the page looks on load. Those fields are already checked for some reason.

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't it be `isset($_GET['all_users_check']`? You also have no submit button, are you going to process this with AJAX?

Comment: I wasn't trying to submit anything with this yet. I just want what is inside of the isset to show up if that checkbox is checked. I do not want the user to have to hit a submit button for the future drop down box to show up. Is AJAX the only way I can make this show with just clicking the checkbox input?

Comment: PHP is server side. Once the page is loaded it is not accessible. An AJAX request will be required, or you could do this with JS/jquery.

Comment: The data will already be there though. I am just wanting to basically hide it until the user clicks that check mark. Unless this cannot be done. I don't want to have the user click a submit button just to move to the next step.

Comment: Yes, so JS will be needed, not PHP. JS runs in the browser, PHP on the server. Start here, https://api.jquery.com/category/events/form-events/.

Comment: Yes, I know that, I just though with the isset statement I could check this without submission. I was mistaken. Thanks for clarifying.....Does anyone know how I could do this with JS?

Comment: @chris85 I updated my question. I am trying this with jquery and it hides the div, but doesn't display it when clicked. Also side note, for some reason whenever I load my page, half of the inputs are already checked? This was happening before as well.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to do the chat. Thanks that helped. I can't believe I didn't catch that. Would you know why half of my checkboxex are loading checked?

Comment: Answer posted, if questions post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issues in your code.

1. `.all_users_check` that is looking for a class. Your element doesn't have a class so this isn't found. You can use a different selector to use the `name` attribute, https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/.
2. This `$(".user_dropdown").hide();` hides your whole form. You might want to move around your divs, or remove that altogether.
3. The `checked` attribute checks the field it is on. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input

> Use the checked attribute to indicate whether this item is selected

```
<div class="user_dropdown">
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="spectator_check" value=""> Spectators<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="member_check" value=""> Team Members<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="commissioner_check" value=""> Commissioner(s)<br>
   <label for="all_users_check">
  <input type="checkbox" name="all_users_check" value=""> Individual User<br>
  </label>
</form>
</div>

<script>
//$(".user_dropdown").hide();
$("input[name='all_users_check']").click(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(".user_dropdown").show();
    } else {
        $(".user_dropdown").hide();
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: I was literally just about to click submit with the exact same solution when the notification appeared!

Comment: @chris85 The show hide is doing what I want. My only concern now is that when I load the page, some of the check box fields are already checked. I want it to load where nothing is checked. I put a pic in my question to illustrate.

Comment: Did you try the code I posted, or update your code to remove the `checked` attribute?

Comment: The checkbox issue with the inputs already being checked was happening before I added the jquery. I want that div to stay hidden until I click the checkbox, so how I had it works better.

Comment: Yea, my comment and answer aren't referring to jquery with the `checked` attribute. Look at my HTML and yours `<input type="checkbox" name="commissioner_check" value="" checked> Commissioner(s)<br>` <-- see it `value="" **checked**`.

Comment: Oh, duh. Yep, that did it. Not sure how those got in there to be honest. Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 2):

[`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) is a language construct and can't accept anything other than a variable as indicated by this warning on the linked to manual page:

> **Warning** isset() only works with variables as passing anything else will result in a parse error.

You are not passing in a variable to the `isset` function, you are passing in a *constant value*, basically an array with a single string `all_users_check`.  This is *not* a variable because you are not assigning it to a variable name.  Try this instead:

```
if(isset($_POST['all_users_check']))
```

Here the variable being passed in is the [superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) `$_POST`, and you are checking to see if the index `all_users_check` is set inside of that array.

**Update**

To check if an input is empty or not via javascript, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937513/javascript-validation-for-empty-input-field).

Answer (score 0):

Try using this script, you have set the state of check boxes as checked by default.

```
<div class="user_dropdown">
<form action="">
  <input type="checkbox" name="spectator_check" value=""> Spectators<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="member_check" value=""> Team Members<br><!-- removed 'checked' from this line -->
  <input type="checkbox" name="commissioner_check" value=""> Commissioner(s)<br><!-- removed 'checked' from this line -->
   <label for="all_users_check">
  <input type="checkbox" name="all_users_check" value="" > Individual User<br> <!-- removed 'checked' from this line -->
  </label>
</form>
</div>

<script>
$(".user_dropdown").hide();
$(".all_users_check").click(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(".user_dropdown").show();
    } else {
        $(".user_dropdown").hide();
    }
});
</script>
```

For the other issue of showing the hidden section again, try whether class all_users_check is visible to click.

Comment: This doesn't throw any errors and hides what is in the isset, but if I check the `all_users_check` it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Ralph, if you have clicked on all_user_check and did not do any form submission, then you cannot find any difference. I think you are expecting a client side solution based on the checked state of the checkbox.

Comment: @Ralph, check the solution above

Comment: There is no `all_users_check` class.