# How to detect that user has input some value in my form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I have one situation where i want detect that user has input some value or not.Let me explain :

I have one registration form where i have user name, email, phone, password this field are there. Now in that form I have two buttons "Save", "Continue".

When user click on "Save" it will fire validation. When click on "Continue" user will have a popup that "Are you sure you do not want to fill the form?" , here without validation fire i would like to user redirect to another page.

How could I overcome this issue? Is there any event that can help me to find out that user did not entered any thing in form? Or any jQuery?

Thanks

Comment: some simple if's will do a fine job

Comment: Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937513/javascript-validation-for-empty-input-field

Comment: if's will create lots of efforts in future. Is there any simplest way ? Sometimes it may happen user has inputted in some fields. I want to catch that event that user view that form but not filled any value.

Comment: _"Is there any simplest way"_ , _"I want to catch that event that user view that form but not filled any value"_ Have you tried approach at Answer using `required` attribute?

Comment: @guest271314 yes i tried "required" but it shows me required alert message. That i don't want to show to user.

Comment: @Meteor Requirement is to not show any message?

Comment: @guest271314 yes. "When click on "Continue" user will have a popup that "Are you sure you do not want to fill the form?" , here without validation fire i would like to user redirect to another page."

Comment: @Meteor See updated post

Answer (score 0):

Have a manual function which tests for form fields when you press the **Continue** button.

```
function isFilled() {

   if ($('#myFields1').value !== ''  && $('#myField2').value !== '') 
      return true
   else
      return false

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `required` attribute at `form` elements. `form` will not be valid if field having `required` attribute without value is present. You can also use `pattern` attribute to specify `RegExp` pattern for valid input.

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<script>
  document.querySelector("form").onsubmit = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  for (input of e.target.querySelectorAll("input")) {
    if (input.value.length === 0) {
      // redirect here
      location.reload();
      break;     
    }
  }
  // else submit form at complete of loop
  this.submit();
}
  </script>
```