# Check if an input with class is empty in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I wrote a code to validate a form on client-side. Since I binded all the error messages `on('input', function())` now the last case to take in consideration is when the user didn't even hit a required input leaving it empty.

If all the inputs in the form were required I could have used something like

```
$('#subButton').on('click', function(e) {
    if (!$('#formName').val()) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("Fill all the required fields");
});
```

But since in my form there are required inputs (with `class="req"`) and non required inputs, I would like to know if there's a method to perform the check **only** on the `.req` inputs.
Something like:

```
$('#subButton').on('click', function(e) {
    if (!$('#formName.req').val()) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("Fill all the required fields");
    }
});
```

In other words I would like to perform the identical check which the up-to-date browsers do if the HTML `required` option is specified, just to be sure that, if the browser is a bit old and doesn't "read" the `required` option, jQuery prevents the form to be sent.

Comment: There are very good jQuery form validation plugins. I would suggest using one of these. Keeps you from writing a lot of code yourself. https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: It is not a great idea to work with the `click` event of a `submit` button on a  `form` as opposed to the `submit` event of the `form` that is triggered by the `click` of a `submit` button.

Comment: @Seb Sure, I check that and the other famous one, but it took me more time trying to figure out how to integrate them in my page (they have a terrible _wiki_ in my opinion) than write the whole validation on my own. I'll anyway try them again probably, for more complex validations. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @ScottMarcus You're right, now I understood what you meant

Answer (score 1):

Just use `.filter` and check the length. Also, a simple `!` check probably isn't good, what if someone enters `0`?

```
var hasEmptyFields = $('#formName.req').filter(function() {
    return this.value.replace(/^\s+/g, '').length; //returns true if empty
    //Stole the above regex from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937513/javascript-validation-for-empty-input-field
}).length > 0

if (hasEmptyFields) {

}
```

Comment: You're totally right about entering the `0`. I tested it but it doesn't work (sure I'm making some mistake); I didn't get what `.length > 0` should do, can you please me explain since I'm quite a newbie in Javascript/jQuery? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```
const submitAllowed = $('.req').toArray().reduce((result, item) => { 
   return result && (!!item.value || item.value === 0);
}, true)

if (!submitAllowed) { ... }
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/lustoykov/sf8mxjw2/3/) is a simple demo:

```
<form action="dummy.asp" onSubmit="return handleSubmit()">
    <p> You can only submit if you enter a name </p>
    <br />
    Enter name: <input class="req" type="text" name="fname">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
  function handleSubmit() {
    const submitAllowed = $('.req').toArray().reduce((result, item) => { 
         return result && (!!item.value || item.value === 0);
      }, true)

    return submitAllowed;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Your way seems to be interesting but I can't actually make it work. `$('.req').toArray()` would put **all** the `<input class="req">` inside an array? And I also didn't get clearly how the "empty check function" is performed on each .req with `reduce`. Sorry but I'm quite a newbie in Javascript/jQuery

Comment: I've edited my answer. you could play around with jsfiddle a bit and things will be clearer I hope. Also read the reduce documentation that I've linked, you'll get it I promise

Answer (score 0):

> But since in my form there are required inputs (with `class="req"`)
>   and non required inputs, I would like to know if there's a method to
>   perform the check only on the `.req` inputs

There is an HTML5 form boolean attribute `required`.

`required` works on:

- `<input type="text" />`
- `<input type="search" />`
- `<input type="url" />`
- `<input type="tel" />`
- `<input type="email" />`
- `<input type="password" />`
- `<input type="date" />`
- `<input type="number" />`
- `<input type="checkbox" />`
- `<input type="radio" />`
- `<input type="file" />`

**Example:**

```css
input {
display: block;
margin: 6px;
}
```

```html
<form action="http://www.stackoverflow.com/">
<input type="text" placeholder="This is required" required />
<input type="text" placeholder="This isn't required" />
<input type="text" placeholder="This is required" required />
<input type="text" placeholder="This isn't required" />
<input type="submit" value="Press Me Without Filling in any of the Fields">
</form>
```

Peculiarly, the *StackOverflow Snippet* above doesn't seem to be working.

Here's a *JSFiddle* to demonstrate what it should be doing:

https://jsfiddle.net/a5tvaab8/

Comment: _"In other words I would like to perform the identical check which the up-to-date browsers do if the HTML required option is specified, just to be sure that, if the browser is a bit old and doesn't "read" the required option, jQuery prevents the form to be sent"_

Comment: Thank you @brigo - that will teach me to stop reading before the end...