# Run function in input if it is empty?

Tags: javascript

Is there anyway I can check if an input is empty using javascript and then run a function? I'd like it to be in the input itself if possible.

There is `onChange` so is there an `ifEmpty` lol?

Comment: Please update the question with the attempted code...

Comment: `if (myElement.value == '') {runFunction();}`[JavaScript validation for empty input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937513/javascript-validation-for-empty-input-field)

Comment: There is no `ifEmpty` attribute/event natively implemented, you need to take care of that by checking whether, on change, the value is effectively "empty" (define empty, anyway). Besides, can you please show what you've tried to accomplish the goal?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input onChange="this.value.trim().length > 0 && myFunction()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
function a(e)
{
if(e.value=="")
return false;
else
console.log('there is a value')
}
```

```html
<input value="" onclick="a(this)">
```