# Checking if inputs fields are filled

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to check if all the input fields are filled in this form, the inputs are created based on the number of players, so I dynamically created them in JavaScript, how can I do that ?
Here is what I tried

```
const x = localStorage.getItem('playersNum');

for (let i = 0; i < x; i++) {

    const newInput = document.createElement("INPUT");
    newInput.setAttribute("type", "text");
    newInput.setAttribute("class", "form-control");
    newInput.setAttribute("id", `player${i}`);
    newInput.setAttribute("placeholder", "Player's Name");
    const parentDiv = document.getElementById('player-list');

    parentDiv.appendChild(newInput);

    const input = document.getElementById(`player${i}`);
    const btn = document.getElementById('startGame');
    btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        if (input === "") {
            alert('Please fill in the players names');
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: one problem is here: `if (input.value === "")`, but beyond this issue what errors do you get on console?

Comment: Plz, provide the complete code! What is `x` here?

Comment: @FabrizioCalderanlovestrees I tried input.value, now the error keeps reloading the number of times depending on the number of players, I think it's because I'm doing it inside the for loop.

Comment: @Moe G 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937513/javascript-validation-for-empty-input-field

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following way:

```js
const parentDiv = document.getElementById('player-list');
for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  const newInput = document.createElement("INPUT");
  newInput.setAttribute("type", "text");
  newInput.setAttribute("class", "form-control");
  newInput.setAttribute("id", `player${i}`);
  newInput.setAttribute("placeholder", "Player's Name");

  parentDiv.appendChild(newInput);
}

//get all input elements of type text and starting id with player
const input = document.querySelectorAll("[type='text'][id^='player']");
const btn = document.getElementById('startGame');
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  //reset border style of all input elements
  [...input].forEach(el => el.style.border = '');
  //get all empty input elements
  let empty = [...input].filter(el => el.value.trim() == "");
  //check length
  if (empty.length) {
    //show alert
    alert('Please fill in the players names');
    //set border style to empty input elements
    empty.forEach(el => el.style.border = '1px solid red');
  }
});
```

```html
<button id="startGame">Start Game</button>
<div id="player-list"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should check if the `input`s are empty and attach an event listener to the start game button only after you've created them: this means after the `for` loop.

As an improvement you could add a `required` attribute on the `input`s and check in `CSS` if they are invalid (using the `:invalid` pseudoclass)

```js
const x = 3; 

const parentDiv = document.getElementById('player-list');
const btn = document.getElementById('startGame');

let players;

for (let i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    const newInput = document.createElement("input");
    newInput.setAttribute("type", "text");
    newInput.setAttribute("required", "required");
    newInput.setAttribute("class", "form-control");
    newInput.setAttribute("id", `player${i}`);
    newInput.setAttribute("placeholder", "Player's Name");
    parentDiv.appendChild(newInput);
}

/*
 * Get all the inputs you have just injected 
 */
players = [...document.querySelectorAll('.form-control')];

/*
 * Check if there are some inputs not filled
 */ 
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (players.some((p) => p.value === '')) {
      alert('Please fill in ALL the players names');
  }
  else {
     alert('Ok');
  }
});
```

```css
input {
   display: block;
   margin: 1rem;
   border: 1px #ccc solid;
   padding: .25rem;
}

input:invalid {
 outline: 1px #aa0020 solid;
 outline-offset: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="player-list"></div>

<button id="startGame">Start Game</button>
```